# Why is FindInstance unable to find multiple pythagorean triples?

Tags: findinstance

If I input the code

```
FindInstance[x^2 + y^2 == z^2 && 0 < x && 0 < y && 0 < z, {x, y, z}, Integers, 2]
```

Mathematica outputs

> "The methods available to FindInstance are insufficient to find the requested instances or prove they do not exist."

Why is it unable to find only two instances of pythagorean triples, of which there are infinite (and plenty of small ones)?

Comment: `FindInstance[
 x^2 + y^2 == z^2 && 0 < x < 100 && 0 < y < 100 && 0 < z < 100, {x, y,
   z}, Integers, 2, RandomSeeding -> Automatic]`

Comment: Amplifying on comment by @OkkesDulgerci, `SortBy[FindInstance[
  x^2 + y^2 == z^2 && 0 < x < 100 && 0 < y < 100 && 0 < z < 100, {x, 
   y, z}, Integers, 104, RandomSeeding -> Automatic], Last]`